# Trying to save pages that contain only specific keyword

Tags: python, web-scraping, web-crawler, scrapy, extract

I'm trying crawl pages which contain a specific keyword and then save the pages that contain that keyword, or at least save the URL that points to that page. I've tried with this code, but it's not helping. Is this even possible?

```python
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider,Rule
import scrapy

import requests
from scrapy.http import Request

from scrapy import signals, Spider
from scrapy.xlib.pydispatch import dispatcher
from scrapy.selector import Selector

import scrapy
from FinalSpider.items import Page  # Defined in items.py

class FinalSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "FinalSpider"
    allowed_domains = ['url']
    start_urls = ['url.com/=%d' %(n)
              for n in range(0, 20)]


def parse(self, response):
    for link in response.xpath('//a[text()="100.00"]/@href').extract():
        yield Request(url=link, callback=self.parse_link)

def parse_link(self, response):
    filename = response.url.split("/")[2] + '.html'
    with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
        f.write(response.body)
```

This is my items.py code:

```python
import scrapy

class Page(scrapy.Item):
    url = scrapy.Field()
```

Comment: I don't see anywhere in your code where you are looking for a keyword. It's collecting links and parsing them so to collect the links use `item['url'] = link` then `yield item` in your parse routine. Also your allowed_domains should  contain url.com using your notation. It's easy to scrape nothing if this is wrong. Can you give us more detail about what isn't working?

Comment: Hi, I've got this resolved thanks to elrull. Thank you for your input though. :)

Comment: No worries. I might be a good idea to post the solution in case it helps someone else. Plus I'm curious too.

Comment: It's located here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34051037/scrapy-access-data-while-crawling-and-randomly-change-user-agent/34052420#34052420 :)