# Scrapy - access data while crawling and randomly change user agent

Tags: python, web-crawler, scrapy

Is it possible to access the data while scrapy is crawling ? I have a script that finds a specific keyword and writes the keyword in .csv as well as the link where it was found. However, I have to wait for scrapy to be done crawling, and when that is done it actually outputs the data in the .csv file

I'm also trying to change my user agent randomly, but it's not working.
If I'm not allowed for two questions in one, i will post this as a separate question.

```html
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*- 
from scrapy.spiders import Spider
from scrapy import log
from FinalSpider.items import Page
from FinalSpider.settings import USER_AGENT_LIST
from FinalSpider.settings import DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES

import random
import telnetlib
import time
 
 
class FinalSpider(Spider):
    name = "FinalSpider"
    allowed_domains = ['url.com']
    start_urls = ['url.com=%d' %(n)
              for n in xrange(62L, 62L)]


    def parse(self, response):
        item = Page()

        item['URL'] = response.url
        item['Stake'] = ''.join(response.xpath('//div[@class="class"]//span[@class="class" or @class="class"]/text()').extract())
        if item['cur'] in [u'50,00', u'100,00']:
            return item

# 30% useragent change
class RandomUserAgentMiddleware(object):
    def process_request(self, request, spider):
        if random.choice(xrange(1,100)) <= 30:
            log.msg('Changing UserAgent')
            ua  = random.choice(USER_AGENT_LIST)
            if ua:
                request.headers.setdefault('User-Agent', ua)
            log.msg('>>>> UserAgent changed')
```

Comment: Could you post the code if possible? So, it would be easier for understanding

Comment: @WoodChopper Ok , there it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not obliged to output your collected items (aka "data") into a csv file, you can only run scrapy with:

```
scrapy crawl myspider
```

This will be outputting the logs into the terminal, but for storing just the items into a csv file I assume you are doing something like this:

```
scrapy crawl myspider -o items.csv
```

Now if you want to store the logs and the items, I suggest you go put this into your `settings.py` file:

```
LOG_FILE = "logfile.log"
```

now you can see something while the spider runs just checking that file.

For your problem with the randomuseragent, please check how to activate [scrapy middlewares](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/downloader-middleware.html#activating-a-downloader-middleware).

Comment: This is what i get when i enabled log file. ScrapyDeprecationWarning: Module `scrapy.log` has been deprecated, Scrapy now relies on the builtin  from scrapy import log